# Splitting string with brackets, spaces, and equal signs

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have the following string and I just want to extract "My Important Text".

```
cssbody=[short_bdy] cssheader=[short_hdr] body=[My Important Text] offsetx=[10] offsety=[20] delay=[300]
```

Comment: This is a [good site](https://pythex.org/) to try out the regex patterns against your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `re.findall` with the pattern:

```
\bbody=\[(.*?)\]
```

Script:

```
inp = "cssbody=[short_bdy] cssheader=[short_hdr] body=[My Important Text] offsetx=[10] offsety=[20] delay=[300]"
matches = re.findall(r'\bbody=\[(.*?)\]', inp)
print(matches[0])
```

This prints:

```
My Important Text
```

Comment: Your regex should be `\bbody=\[([^]]*)\]`.

Comment: @fedup I am not making any assumptions about _which_ match the OP would want to retain (as his sample data only shows a single match).

Comment: If you want to match as many as you can find then `(?:(?:^|\b)body=\[([^]]*)\])`. Translated to english reads as, I want all non-closing-bracket characters between brackets that follow the characters "body=" as long as "body=" is at the beginning of the string or in the middle preceded by a space.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen your assumption was correct and thanks for the help. I have a love/hate relationship with regex - I have not used \b word boundaries before so will read up on it.

Comment: @Bill And regex probably feels the same way about us :-)